# Retrieve custom variable from a successful jenkins job run via REST api call

Tags: rest, curl, jenkins, groovy

I would like to retrieve a custom variable from a successful last stable build jenkins job. I was able to retrieve the build number using curl on this link using Execute Shell. It's an internal server. https://jenkinsci.internalsvr/view/webapps/job/common-tools/lastStableBuild/buildNumber

Now, I'd like to do the same for a custom variable using curl. But I know that I may need to save the value of the custom variable but not sure how and to where.

Comment: As a workaround you can save its value in a text file and then archive that file as an artifact. Then curl/wget it.

Comment: Cool but when I archive it, what's the link that I wil curl or wget? Let's say the filename is info.txt I haven't tried archiving that's why I'm kinda lost. Thanks!

Comment: I finally got it working! WOOHOO! I archived it and accessed the artifact url.

Comment: @devwannabe By "custom variable" do you mean job's parameter or variable from build step?

Comment: Please add your solution or workaroind as answer, so others can learn from it.

Comment: I just added my solution @DominikGebhart

Answer (score 2):

So this is how I got it to work

I have this code in our dsl.groovy file

```
....

parameters {
    stringParam('CUSTOM_VAR1', '', 'Custom Variable')
    stringParam('CUSTOM_VAR2', '', 'Custom Variable')
}

shellCommands = sprintf('''#/bin/bash
echo "CUSTOM_VAR1=\${%s}" > env.properties
echo "CUSTOM_VAR2=\${%s}" >> env.properties
''', ['CUSTOM_VARIABLE1','CUSTOM_VARIABLE1'])

shell(shellCommands)

// This is extremely important
environmentVariables {
  propertiesFile('env.properties')
}

// This allowed me to retrieve env.properties via http call from browser or curl.

publishers {
  archiveArtifacts {
    pattern('env.properties')
  }
}
```

So if I need to access it, the http url should be formed like this

```
curl https://our-internal-server/job/theNameOfTheJob/lastStableBuild/artifact/env.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the API of the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), either with:

```
curl <jenkins-host>/job/<job_name>/<buildNumber>/injectedEnvVars/export
curl <jenkins-host>/job/<job_name>/<buildNumber>/injectedEnvVars/api/python
```

More info [here](https://github.com/pycontribs/jenkinsapi/issues/489).